# Heroku, apparent silent failure of sucker_punch

Tags: heroku, delayed-execution

My app runs on Heroku with unicorn and uses [sucker_punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch) to send a small quantity of emails in the background without slowing the web UI. This has been working pretty well for a few weeks.

I changed the unicorn config to the Heroku recommended config. The recommended config
includes an option for the number of unicorn processes and I upped the number of processes from 2 to 3.

Apparently that was too much. The sucker_punch jobs stopped running. I have log messages that indicate when they are queued and I have messages that indicate when they start processing. The log shows them being queued but the processing never starts.

My theory is that I exceeded memory by going from 2 to 3 unicorns.

I did not find a message anywhere indicating a problem.

Q1: should I expect to find a failure messsage somewhere? Something like "attempting to start sucker_punch -- oops, not enough memory"?

Q2: Any suggestions on how I can be notified of a failure like this in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed exceeding dyno memory, you should find R14 or R15 errors in your logs. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded

A more likely problem, though, given that you haven't found these errors, is that something within the `perform` method of your sucker punch worker is throwing an exception. I've found sucker punch tasks to be a pain to debug because it appears the lib swallows all exceptions silently. Try instantiating your task and calling perform on it from a rails console to make sure that it behaves as you expect.

For example, you should be able to do this without causing an exception:

```
task = YourTask.new
task.perform :something, 55
```